# Autowired instância com valor nulo

Tags: java, spring-boot, ioc

## Problema

Estou trabalhando em um projeto Spring Boot que depende de outros projeto, estes projetos estão as minhas entidades, services e afins.

Eu utilizo a anotação `Autowired` para injetar as minhas dependências, exemplo:

```
@Autowired
TermService termService;
```

Funciona perfeitamente no meu `controller`, contudo o projeto cresceu e decidir criar novas classes em um novo pacote.

E é ai que surge o problema, quando utilizo o `Autowired` nestas novas classes não é injetada a dependência e o objeto permanece nulo.

Pesquisei e a única coisa que encontrei foi colocar a anotação `Component` nas classes, porem não funcionou.

## Estrutura do projeto

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Poste mais detalhes sobre a estrutura do seu projeto, bem como a estrutura da sua dependencia

Comment: É um projeto convencional Spring Boot, não tem nenhuma configuração especial.

Comment: Podem ser várias coisas, sem a estrutura do projeto não tem como ajudar

Comment: Mas o que você precisa? Porque se for postar toda a estrutura do projeto a pergunta ficará gigante, como eu disse anteriormente é uma estrutura convencional de um projeto Spring Boot, como é um projeto padrão não vejo necessidade de postar esta parte que todo projeto Spring Boot tem.

Comment: Tudo de novo que fiz esta na pergunta, criei um pacote e criei novas classes dentro deste pacote, é isso que há de novo no projeto.

Comment: Estrutura de pacotes, a classe principal anotada com `@SpringBootApplication`, o pacote e a classe apresentando problema de injeção (tudo com imports :) )

Comment: A classe com a anotação "SpringBootApplication" não há alterações, é como em um projeto novo, só tem o "main" e lá dentro o comando "SpringApplication.run(nomeDaclas..."

Comment: Agora a classe é uma classe nova também, não tem nada nela, simplesmente criei uma classe nova e peguei o código que estava na controller e coloquei lá.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/102679/discussion-between-nullptr-and-wictor-chaves).

Comment: O que acontece é que quando coloco o "Autowired" nesta nova classe a injeção não funciona.

Comment: Concordo com o @nullptr sobre postar mais detalhes. A nomenclatura e organização dos diretórios do projeto influenciam muito projetos Spring.

Comment: Um print da organização pela IDE já ajuda.

Comment: @Gustavo alterei a pergunta e coloquei o print da estrutura, a pasta "build" foi a que eu criei

Comment: Parece OK. Em algum lugar do seu código vc usa sem injeção do spring: `new TermService()` ?

Comment: Tenho que escrever muita coisa para poder enviar a resposta, a resposta é: Não

Comment: Já usou o packageScan?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Problema

Utilizei o "Autowired" em uma classe que instanciei manualmente, ou seja utilizei "new" para utiliza-lá, desta forma o Spring não faz a injeção da dependência.

## Solução

A classe que era instanciada manualmente coloque a anotação "@Component", assim todas as suas dependências foram preenchidas.

Answer (score 0):

Ajudaria saber a versão que está usando, mas vamos lá.

Use a anotação Spring `@ComponentScan` ao lado do `@SpringBootApplication` e configure o pacote base personalizado (você pode especificar uma lista de nomes de pacotes ou uma lista de classes cujo pacote será usado), por exemplo:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"outroPacote", "..."})
public class Application
```

Ou

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(basePackageClasses = {otherpackage.MyClass.class, ...})
public class Application
```

Ou se está usando uma versão que é a partir da Spring 1.3.0, você pode escrever diretamente:

```
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackageClasses = {otherpackage.MyClass.class, ...})
public class Application
```

Observe que o 'component scan' encontrará classes dentro e abaixo dos pacotes que colocou.